# How would you replace page with HTML from Rest API response? (AngularJS/NodeJS)

Tags: angularjs, rest, express

We have a decoupled AngularJS (1.8) application and Node.JS serving it and we are trying to allow server-side rendering of a view.

From Node (added as a route, response is HTML):

```
  if (req.query.username) {
    // initializes secondary authentication process
    let frame = <SOME HTML IFRAME>
    // shows the IFrame
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    res.end(frame)
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    res.end(`Make sure you add a username `)
  }
};
```

In my AngularJS controller (getSomeIFrameUrl hits the Node.JS route):

```
    $scope.generateSomeIFrame = function () {
      let email = $rootScope.user.email
      $http.get(serverConfig.getSomeIFrameUrl(email))
      .then(function mySuccess(response) {
          $scope.view2FAPiece = response.data;
      }, function myError(response) {
          console.log("Error : ", response.data.errors);
      });
    };
```

On the HTML page (generateSomeIFrame calls the function in the AngularJS controller to make http.get request):

```
    <button ng-click="generateSomeIFrame($rootScope.user)"> IFrame Generator</button>
    <p>{{ view2FAPiece }}</p>
```

Currently, it only displays the response (HTML) as a string on the page, how would I render the page to refresh and render the HTML from the response?
Alternatively, how would we render the HTML in a separate window?

Comment: You can create simple component that it using for its template the returned response html.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take in the HTML into $scope.htmlFromAPI and display ng-bind-html='htmlFromAPI'.

Sadly the iFrame does not display, but that is the next step in the process.